# Multiplication or sum of two numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-2.7, for-loop

Given two integer numbers, return their product only
if the product is equal to or less than 1000, else return their sum.

```py
def multiplication_or_sum(num1, num2):
    product = num1 * num2
    if product < = 1000:
        return product
    else:
        return num1 + num2

result = multiplication_or_sum(20,30)
print("The result is = ", result)


result = multiplication_or_sum(50,10)
print("The result is = ", result)
```

my output

```
The result is =  600
The result is =  500
```

expected output

```
The result is =  600
The result is =  60
```

but I can't figure out the error.

Comment: Expected output looks wrong

Comment: *Why* do you think that's the expected output when your rules clearly indicate the observed output is the correct output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> if the product is equal to or lower than 1000, else return their sum.

```
if x*y <= 1000:
   return x*y
else:
   return x+y
```

20 * 30 = 600
600 < 1000
return 600

50 * 10 = 500
500 < 1000
return 500

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If there is not anything wrong, then there is not a question, and answers should not be attempted. At 50 reputation you can comment on the question to explain such things.

Answer (score -2):

The expected output looks good to me.

But, in case you were wondering: can I do this in one line with python? the answer is yes:

```py
def multiplication_or_sum(num1, num2):
    return num1*num2 if num1*num2 <= 1000 else num1+num2
```

Comment: If there is not anything wrong, then there is not a question, and answers should not be attempted. Instead, please comment to explain this (if nobody else has already). At 3000 reputation you can help vote to close the question as not reproducible. Especially please do not invent your own question to answer.

Answer (score -2):

For python3.8+ code can be:

```py
def multiplication_or_sum(num1: int, num2: int) -> int:
    if (product := num1 * num2) <= 1000:
        return product
    return num1 + num2
```

Comment: OP's code works as intended, and the only issue is with the expectation for the code. There is not a question here, because there is not a reproducible issue, so please do not attempt to answer. Instead, help vote to close the question.